# Cant perform simple write to Google Cloud Bucket

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore, buckets

I cannot do a simple write operation on my Google Cloud Bucket. I have followed the docs to the detail. This is what I have: A default bucket, A php script, all api needed enabled.

Here is my script

```
<?php
   file_put_contents('gs://myappid.appspot.com/hello.txt', 'Hello');
?>
```

Yet this does not write. What am I missing?

Comment: what do your app logs say? are you sure you are writing to the correct bucket?

Comment: @StuartLangley I am not using an app. I am logged in to my remote google cloud VM server and I am just using this php script to try to write to the bucket when I run it.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're using a GCE VM and not AppEngine? Your example is very app engine specific. file_put_contents('gs://...') is an App Engine thing and doesn't work with in a normal PHP environment. Doing this in normal PHP is more involved. Here is an example: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough Yes GCE VM and not AppEngine and I will try this method you gave and let you know

Comment: Hi, I'm a representative of Google Cloud Platform. Were you able to solve this issue by following @Brandon suggestion?

Comment: @Mario I just tried it and no I was not able to. I am unsure what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

According to the [latest docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/signup#activate) you seem to also need to have billing enabled, even if you are only planning to use the free quota.

Comment: @superuserdo Try enabling "Cloud Integration" at the bottom of the page in the "Application Settings" menu of the old AppEngine console (https://appengine.google.com/). I think that what made it working for me in the end.